# what can be used to save structures like graphics in c ++ (Python pickle equivalent)

Tags: c++, graph, pickle

I have a graph structre with edges and vertices. I want to seriliaze and save it like pickling in python. What can ı use for that?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not support general serialization natively.

So, you have 3 options:

1. Search in google for "c++ serialization library" and use it
2. Write it for a class by yourself
3. Use standards like JSON

For 2.:

Normally you have all data for your graph in one class. The only thing that you need to do, is to overwrite the inserter `operator <<` and the extractor `operator` for your class.

I give you a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream testFile(R"(1 2 3
10 11 12)");

struct Graph
{
    int x,y;                  // Some example data
    int numberOfEdges;        // The number of elements in the vector
    std::vector<int> edges;   // An array of data

    // Serializing. Put the data into a character stream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Graph& g) {
        os << g.x << ' ' << g.y << ' '<< g.numberOfEdges << '\n';
        std::copy(g.edges.begin(), g.edges.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
        return os;
    }

    // Deserializing. Get the data from a stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Graph& g) {
        is >> g.x >> g.y >> g.numberOfEdges;
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), g.numberOfEdges, std::back_inserter(g.edges));
        return is;
    }
};

// Test program
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Graph graph{};

    // Read graph data from a file --> Deserializing
    testFile >> graph;
    // Put result to std::cout --> Serializing
    std::cout << graph;

    return 0;
}
```